# How can I turn a directory of images into video? (node.js)

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to create a screen recording video by using a module to create multiple images and then somehow use these images to export to an mp4. However I don't know how to turn the directory of images into a video. Can anyone help with this?

Here is what I have so far:

```
const screenshot = require('desktop-screenshot');

let i = 0;
while(i <= 100){ 
    screenshot("screens/" + i + "_shot.png", function(error, complete) {
        if(error){
          console.log("Screenshot failed", error);
        }
        else{
          console.log("Screenshot succeeded");        
        }

    });
       i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use an npm package for screen recording?

Also your while loop doesn't represent seconds but discrete steps. If you want a time based recording you need some implementation which respects time based steps with step delta to allow adjustment for different rendering speeds. (This is similar to game loops, the only difference is that your action is screen captures and not moving game characters.)

A good screen recording package should do that, as well as providing an API for export. Save your time and effort and use a package for that.

Good point to start: https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=screen+recording